# Error at OneToOneField in models while creating new models class django

Tags: django, django-models

I am facing below error while creating a new model class.
the error pop up only at this line "user = models.OneToOneField(User)"
"E1120:No value for argument 'on_delete' in constructor call"

section/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class userProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from section.models import userProfile

admin.site.register(userProfile)
```

If I add below entry with "on_delete=models.CASCADE"

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the error got subsided but the new class "userProfile" is not appearing in admin page, under Users tab.

Also run migrations:

```
C:\Users\srini\djangoProjects\college>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected

C:\Users\srini\djangoProjects\college>python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
```

Could some one please guide me how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you add a `ModelAdmin` for this model?

Comment: Yes, updated my question with admin entries.

Comment: Did you run migrations?

Comment: Yes, added the migration output as well in question, please review, it says no changes detected.

Comment: Try this: python manage.py makemigrations <AppName> >>  python manage.py migrate --fake-initial

Comment: C:\Users\srini\djangoProjects\college>python manage.py makemigrations section
App 'section' could not be found. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS'  \n the section app is there**, not sure why it telling like this?

Comment: look https://github.com/srinivasgadi77/college/issues/2 I will fix it there.

Comment: done, fixed it.

Comment: Here is the complete issue description https://github.com/srinivasgadi77/college/pull/1#issuecomment-424407821

Answer (score 2):

Include your app_name in `INSTALLED_APPS` list in settings.py.

Then try migrations. After that check Admin after running the server.

Comment: Treied ,getting the below error
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sectiondjango'"

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you please post the code from you settings file.