# When I click on submit button on login page, its redirecting to an random csrf token page in django

Tags: django

I modified my complete questions to fix subsequent errors.
1) in forms.py, when I tries to save it highlighting syntax error, but not sure exact cause.
2) in my views.py, post save the changes, it highlighted with "E0401:Unable to import 'section.forms'", is this due to error in forms.py?

section/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        models = User
        fields = (
                'username',
                'first_name',
                'last_name',
                'email',
                'password1',
                'password2',
        )
        def save(self, commit=True):
            user=super(RegistrationForm,self).save(commit=False)
            user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
            uesr.last_name = self.cleaned_data(['last_name']
            user.email = self.cleaned_data['email'] #its prompting some errors here, not sure what exctly that
            if commit:
                user.save()

            return user
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse
from section.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def register(request):
    if  request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():        
            form.save()
            print('data has been saved')
            return redirect(reverse('home_page'))

    form = RegistrationForm()
    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'section/reg_form.html',args)
```

Comment: I have update your code view indentation, which error you have with your code ? Maybe you must correct your indentation...

Comment: There is some confusion with names. Login pages don't save data, authenticate users. You mean _register_ form gives the error? And what is exactly the csrf error?

Comment: have you solved your issue and wich version of django you use ?

Comment: Thank you very much, Identified that there are two issues, once of them you identified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an error in your form:

You set `action="post"` but it is `method="post"`

Comment: Thank you very much, Identified that there are two issues, once of them you identified.

Answer (score 0):

```
url(r'home',views.home, name='home page')
return redirect('section/home')
```

Instead of this Try This.

```
url(r'home',views.home, name='home')
return redirect('/home')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets start from top

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import login, logout

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home),
    url(r'home',views.home, name='home_page'), # name should be one word
    url(r'login',login,{'template_name':'section/login.html'}),
    url(r'logout',logout,{'template_name':'section/logout.html'}),
    url(r'register',views.register, name='register'), # trailing comma, not required but good practice
]
```

views

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse, render # etc
def register(request):
    if  request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): # is_valid() is a method you need to call it, so parenthesis is required, otherwise it will always return true
            form.save()
            print('data has been saved')
            # return redirect('section/home') # hardcoded urls, dont't do it
            return redirect(reverse('home_page'))  # Right way to do it, use reverse

    # else:  # unnecessary else after return, can be skipped
    form = UserCreationForm()
    args={'form':form}
    return render(request,'section/reg_form.html',args)
```

Template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<br><br><br>
<form method="POST"> <!-- Method is POST not action -->
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type='submit'>Login</button>
</form>
{% endblock  %}
```

Now what you are doing in your view is not doing anything that may be of any actual use. Button name in template suggests it's a login form, but everything else suggests you are trying to create a user. Creating users like this will save passwords un-encrypted. The correct way to create user is:

```
..
if form.is_valid():
    # form.save() # Nope
    user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['password']) # assuming name of your auth model is User
    print('data has been saved')
    return redirect(reverse('home_page'))
```

Comment: Thank you for spotted all my mistakes and corrections.its working now.

Comment: But your suggested way of gives me some error " user = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['username'], form.cleaned_data['email'], form.cleaned_data['password']) # assuming name of your auth model is User
KeyError: 'email'"    and more over , I tried to print the form 'form.cleaned_data' dictionary, it gives me blow values , there is no password and email keys words. data :     "{'username': 'test8', 'password1': '12345678', 'password2': '12345678'}"

Comment: And also, how to save the data stored in "user" variable since form.save() commented out ?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I have refined the my question and post the forms.py and views.py, could you review and spot me the errors.

Comment: The indentation was correct in my local , I guess it messed while pasting here, you can see that my here https://github.com/srinivasgadi77/college/blob/master/section/forms.py , it is exactly that what you suggest, but it throwing the error following error        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email'] 
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thank you very much and appreciate your help.

Comment: I pity myself and overlooked my code. You are the best.can I have your mail id please,i have another issue will share my code.

Comment: If you have time, could you also review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52455206/error-at-onetoonefield-in-models-while-creating-new-models-class-django .